# Image not Found on HTML (webpack)

Tags: html, css, webpack

I am trying to show an image:

```
<img class="header__logo" src="src\assets\image.png" alt="Logo">
```

The project:

```
/node_modules
/src
|- /assets
  |- image.png
|- /scss
|- app.js
|- index.html
pakckage.json
webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      template: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      }
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8600
  }
};
```

I do not know what happened because I have other projects with the same configuration and they show the images correctly.

Thanks! :D

Comment: `asseets` -> typo?

Comment: Yes, I edited it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to link an image using escape characters (i.e. backwards slashes `\`).

Your issue can be solved if you replace them with regular forward slashes (`/`) like so:

```
<img class="header__logo" src="src/assets/image.png" alt="Logo">
```